# Create a new column in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How do i create a new column in data frame that will say "Cheap" if the price is below 50000, "Fair" is the price is between 50000 and 100000 and "Expensive" if the price is over 100000[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdE9R.png)

Answer (score 2):

Although I think @mozway's solution is the cleanest one, here is another way using [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
import numpy as np

df['new_column'] = np.select([df['selling_price'] < 50_000, 
                              df['selling_price'] <= 100_000], 
                             ['Cheap', 'Fair'], 'Expensive')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. A nice one is [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.cut(df['selling_price'],
                   bins=[0,50000,100000, float('inf')],
                   labels=['cheap', 'fair', 'expensive'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy.where() for this kind of data processing:

```
import numpy as np
df['Cheap']=np.where(df['selling_price']<=50000,'Cheap', #When selling_price <50k, 'Cheap', otherwise...
                     np.where((df['selling_price']>50000) & (df['selling_price']<100000) ,'Fair', #When selling_price >50k and <100k, 'Fair', otherwise...
                     np.where(df['selling_price']>=100000,'Expensive',#When selling_price >100k, Expensive
                    'N/A')))#Otherwise N/A - in case you have some string or other data type in your data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `apply()` and `lambda` function :

```
df["new"] = df.selling_price.apply(
    lambda x: "cheap" if x < 50000 else 
        "fair" if x < 100000 else 
        "expensive"
)
```

Or in a general way which allows you to include multiple columns in the condition :

```
df["new"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: "cheap"
    if x["selling_price"] < 50000
    else "fair"
    if x["selling_price"] < 100000
    else "expensive",
    axis=1,
)
```